# ¿Cómo matar un hilo cuando termine en vez de tener que esperarlo (sin matar el hilo principal)?

Tags: c++, hilos, socket

Tengo un problema de diseño con Threads en el lado de un servidor.

Me gustaría matar los hilos una vez acaben su trabajo en vez tener que esperarlos para que no estén ocupando memoria y para no tener que matar el hilo principal también.

He intentado usar `std::terminate()` pero el programa explota. Puede que tenga algo que ver con que estoy usando los threads de POSIX en vez de los de C++ pero no estoy seguro de eso.

Este es el código:

```
///-----------------------------------------------
///-----------------------------------------------
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include "../PThread.h"
#include "Server.h"
///-----------------------------------------------
using namespace std;
///-----------------------------------------------
int countThreads=0;
bool isLaunched=false;
bool isDone=false;
///-----------------------------------------------
///-----------------------------------------------
//funcion para poder terminar el programa
void *Exit(void *param)
{
    char c;
    cin >> c;
    isDone=true;
    exit(0);
    return NULL;
}
///-----------------------------------------------
///-----------------------------------------------
void *ProcessData(void *param)
{

    Server *server = (Server*) param;

    cout<<countThreads<<" waiting "<< endl;

    //esperar a un cliente
    server->WaitForClient();

    //recibir el tamaño de los datos
    int pSize = 0;
    if(!server->Recive( (char*)&pSize, sizeof(int)))
    {
        cout<<"Error al recibir el tamaño de los datos --> "<<endl;
        return NULL;
    }

    Trade *trade = new Trade[pSize+1];

    //recibir los datos
    for(int i=0; i<pSize; i++) server->Recive((char*)&trade[i], sizeof(Trade));

    delete[] trade;

    //permitir que se lance otro hilo
    isLaunched = false;

    ///std::terminate();///--> no sirve
    return NULL;
}
///-----------------------------------------------
///-----------------------------------------------
int main()
{
    cout << "--SERVER--" << endl;

    PThread processThread[10000];
    

    //Lanzar el hilo para poder salir del programa
    PThread exitThread;
    exitThread.Create(Exit, NULL);
    cout<< "Exit Thread Created"<< endl;

    //Inicializa el socket del server
    Server server;
    cout<< "Serever Created"<<endl;


    while(!isDone)
    {
        if(!isLaunched)
        {
            //Lanzar un hilo cada vez que haya una conexión
            processThread[countThreads].Create(ProcessData, (Server*)&server);
            processThread[countThreads].Detach();

            countThreads++;
            isLaunched = true;
        }

        //Esperar unos milisegundos antes de lanzar el siguente hilo
        //si no se hace esto los clientes no logran conectarse correctamente al servidor
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
    }

    //Por como está diseñado el programa nunca ejecuta las 
    //lineas que están por abajo de este comentario    

    for (int i = 0; i < countThreads; i++)
    {
        cout<< "Esperando hilos del Server -->"<< i <<endl;
        processThread[countThreads].Wait();
    }


    exitThread.Wait();
    return 0;
}
///-----------------------------------------------
///-----------------------------------------------
```

NOTA: He pensado que con este código es más que suficiente para ver el problema. Pero si quieren ver el contenido de los archivos  "PThread.h" y "Server.h" me lo dicen y también los añado. No son más que unos envoltorios para las funciones de *pthreads* de POSIX y el *sockets* de Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, al final lo gonseguí:

```
 //esta es para que un hilo se suicidie
 static void Exit(void *retval=NULL)
 {
     pthread_exit(retval);
 }

 //y esta es para matarlo desde otro proceso
 void kill()
 {    
    const auto explorer = OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE, false,handler);
    TerminateProcess(explorer, 1);
    CloseHandle(explorer);
 }

//tal vez esto también pueda ser útil según el caso
 pthread_t ptid = pthread_self();
```

Saludos!!